# Is there a better performing alternative to read and show in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, serialization

I am writing a networking prototype where a `Server` transmits the state of the `World` to all of its `Clients`. I do this using the following workflow:

```
Server --> World --> show --> ByteString --> GZip.compress   --> udp send
Client <-- World <-- read <-- ByteString <-- GZip.decompress <-- udp receive
```

However, it appears that `show` and `read` are performance bottlenecks - taking up the majority of the time. As the `World` grows, this will only prove a great challenge.

I know that I'll have to stop sending the whole world at some point, but are there any alternatives to using `read` and `show` to convert a data structure into a `ByteString`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the [binary package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary) provides very efficient de-/serialization to/from binary formats.

EDIT: Code was requested, this is the `Generic` example from the (BSD3) documentation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Binary
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Foo = Foo
         deriving (Generic)

-- GHC will automatically fill out the instance
instance Binary Foo
```

Then you can e.g. use `encode` instead of `show` and `decode` instead of `read`. Note that the package has several other functions that may be useful, and that the format may be customized.

Comment: Thank you! I spent about 25 minutes using the generic derived instances and the difference is astounding.

Comment: Please try to avoid link only answers rather to add relevant code here.

Comment: @Hinata I didn't think this was necessary in this case, since that would just mean cutting and pasting from the good examples on the linked site, which is essentially the official documentation site of the package. But I guess I can do that for the short `Generic` example.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen thanks for that - the reason why this site does not like link only answer is that these sites might vanish (official reason) and that most asking here are to lazy to visit this site and search/read/adapt the things written there ;)